# How to Make Appbar Background Color Transparent in Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I cannot figure out how to make the [app-bar in vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#app-bars) transparent.  I tried adding the property `color="transparent"`, but that did not work.  I tried `color="rgba(0,0,0, 0)"`, but that did not work.  I tried `color="shades.transparent"` - and that also did not work.

I can't figure it out.  Any idea how to make this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Transparent is working, see this pen. https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/qBbVNWG. Have you loaded vuetify colors?

Comment: I removed `inverted-scroll` and tested it out.  It is transparent IF I scroll down.  Any idea how to get it to be transparent even if I do not scroll down.

Comment: I think that what you are saying is when you remove inverted scroll you have an app bar with white color, but it changes as you scroll down... Is this is your concern?

Comment: Yes -- I want it to be transparent all the time.  Not just when i scroll down.

Answer (score 10):

Well if you want to have the app bar transparent only when it is on top or in certain distance of top you can use window.onscroll to change the background color.

```
<v-app-bar :color="bg">...</v-app-bar>
```

then in your script section

```
mounted() {
    window.onscroll = () => {
      this.changeColor();
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeColor() {
      if (
        document.body.scrollTop > 100 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100
      ) {
        this.bg = 'white';
      } else {
        this.bg = 'transparent';
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what i needed to make v-app-bar transparent at top, but any scrolling down will cause it to change color! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a fixed appbar the vuetify applies a equal padding to the v-content, Inorder to remove this padding and pull the content up, you can use class="pa-0". Then the v-content will start from top of screen and makes the transparent appbar visible. I hope that makes sense.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/qBbVNWG

```
<v-app app>
    <v-app-bar app color="transparent">
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content class="ma-0 pa-0">
       <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-center" width="900">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300"/>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300"/>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/300"/>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300"/>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300"/>
      </div>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to off this transparency when scroll? I mean, it will transparent only when scrolltop.

Comment: What you are looking for is an inverted scroll app-bar. https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/YzXwgbR https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#inverted-scrolling

Comment: @AneesHameed I think that's not work after alll.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still having trouble with this, but I figured I'd at least post my solution for anyone else who may be having this issue.

I'm using Vuetify with Nuxtjs, and I was able to find the element that applies the background color in my Chrome Dev Tools.

```
.theme--light.v-app-bar.v-toolbar.v-sheet{
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

I copy-and-pasted it into the styles of my default.vue file and changed it to:

```
.theme--light.v-app-bar.v-toolbar.v-sheet {
    background: transparent;
}
```

And that seems to have done the trick for me.